# UITextfield not removing the icon even after the textfield is cleared

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a form with two textfields and I want to validate those as I type. For example: I have an email textfield and as soon as I start typing it tells me whether the email has been previously used or not. If it is already used it shows an 'X' icon in the textfield and if it's not it shows a 'check mark'. The validation works fine. The problem I am facing is when I try to clear the textfield by pressing the delete button(not holding down) it clears the textfield and shows no icon because it's empty. But if it try to clear the textfield by holding down the delete button, then the icon does not disappear. Here's the code:

```
  EmailAvailable.get(["email": newString], handler: {(result: [BaseModel]?,  error: NSError?) in
                if let available = result as? [EmailAvailable] {
                    self.emailImageView.image = available[0].available ? UIImage(named: "success") : UIImage(named: "failed")
                } else {
                    self.emailImageView.image = UIImage(named: "failed")
                }
            })
```

I am making an API call here to check whether the email is valid or not. NOTE: The validation works fine.

[image]

the above image shows the check mark even after the textfield is cleared and only happens when I hold down the delete button. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Call invalidate()  on emailImageView after update value

Comment: @christianmini not sure what you are saying, but not able to call invalidate() on emailImageView

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean try to invalidate your view by calling setNeedsDisplay

Comment: You can use the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and write your code for what should happen when you press down delete button.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 that won't work as i have to validate the field as I start typing in

Comment: Validate it in `textFieldDidEndEditing`?? Makes sense, don't you think?

Comment: Try putting it in the main thread using `dispatch_async()`

Comment: @Dershowitz123 hmm doesn't work